# How can I fill a Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hi all I have a question about how can I add Items to a dropdownlist with some attributes. My first Idea was:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV_Area" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" CssClass="table table-striped bolsa-table-gv text-center"
                                                            DataKeyNames="Area,Oferta">
       <Columns>
             <asp:BoundField DataField="Nombre" HeaderText="Nombre" ReadOnly="true" />
                     <asp:TemplateField>
                             <ItemTemplate>
                                   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Especializaciones" runat="server" CssClass="selectpicker" multiple DataSource='<%#GetDropDownData(Container)%>'></asp:DropDownList>
                             </ItemTemplate>
                     </asp:TemplateField>
       </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

And in the code:

```
    Protected Function GetDropDownData(e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRow) As ListItem()

            Dim item As ListItem = New ListItem
            Dim arr As ArrayList = New ArrayList

            item.Selected = True
            item.Text = "Hello"
            item.Value = "Hello2"
            arr.Add(item)

            Return arr
        End Function
```

The elements are included correctly in the dropdownlist but only with the text attribute. The selected and the value is not working. What do you think I'm doing wrong or, can I do it easily in another way?

Thanks a million for the help

Comment: Maybe try wiring up a handler for the DropDownList's (ddl_Especializaciones) DataBound event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the DropDownList in a GridView, the easiest way to fill them with data is to use the `OnRowDataBound` event.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GV_Area" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GV_Area_RowDataBound">
```

Code behind

```
Protected Sub GV_Area_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs)

    'check if the row is a datarow
    If (e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow) Then

        'cast the row back to a datarowview
        Dim row As DataRowView = CType(e.Row.DataItem,DataRowView)

        'use findcontrol to locate the dropdownlist
        Dim ddl As DropDownList = CType(e.Row.FindControl("ddl_Especializaciones"),DropDownList)

        'if you need to use a datasource value for filling the dropdownlist
        Dim Nombre As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(row("Nombre"))

        'now fill the dropdownlist with values

        'from a datasource, where 'textField' and `valueField` are colums/properties of the datasource
        ddl.DataSource = Common.LoadFromDB
        ddl.DataTextField = "textField"
        ddl.DataValueField = "valueField"
        ddl.DataBind

        'or add them manually
        ddl.Items.Insert(0, New ListItem("Item A", "1", true))
        ddl.Items.Insert(1, New ListItem("item B", "1", true))

    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a million!